# SFML getGlobalBounds( ).intersect(getGlobalBounds( ) not Working

Tags: c++, function, sfml

I just try got collsion from shipshape and asteroidshape but getGlobalBounds nothing happning.Im doing anything wrong? please help me.
In Spaceship.hpp have a bool function.Very strange but the i need create any variable for reference to getGlobalBounds?

I just put a code here from Spaceship.cpp for clarify.

```
  Spaceship.hpp
  .....
   class Spaceship: public sf::Drawable, public sf::Transformable {
    ......
     public:

      bool shipcollisionAsteroid(sf::ConvexShape shapeship, sf::ConvexShape shape);

    .......
     .......
     private:
      sf::Convexshape shapeship;


  };
#endif
//==================================================
  Spaceship.cpp
  #include "Spaceship.hpp"
   ....
     ......
       .....

  sf::ConvexShape shape; // same name in private Asteroid,hpp BUT NOT WORKING
    if ( shapeship.getGlobalBounds().intersects(shape.getGlobalBounds())){

        reset(); // its a function for reset Spaceship on screen


     }
```

Comment: i need know if GlobalBounds its a virtual rectangle and follow objects in case Spaceship and Asteroids?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post more code? It's hard to find the problem only looking at this snippet. Show your asteroid file

Comment: here is my full code.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58592628/sfml-how-can-made-correct-collision-bullet-to-convexshape-polygon-asteroidobs